# Error when testing lambda statusCode":400,"body":"\"Unsupported route: \\\"undefined

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I am attempting to do this as a home lab https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/2c8321cb-812c-45a9-927d-206eea3a500f/en-US/080-test-your-api.
I got it working by using the AWS Console, now I am trying to do it via Terraform.

In Cloud9 after invoking the url I run

```
curl -X "PUT" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{
    \"id\": \"abcdef234\",
    \"price\": 12345,
    \"name\": \"myitem\"
}" $INVOKE_URL/items
```

and in return I get

```
{"message":"Not Found"}
```

When trying to do a test in vscode I used

```
 aws lambda invoke --region=us-east-1 --function-name=$(terraform output -raw function_name) 
response.json
```

Interestingly after running this in the terminal I get

```
{e  
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "ExecutedVersion": "$LATEST"
}
```

But when looking at the response.json file the output is

```
{"statusCode":400,"body":"\"Unsupported route: \\\"undefined\\\"\"","headers":{"Content-Type":"application/json"}}
```

My Lambda Code:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

const dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  let body;
  let statusCode = 200;
  const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  };

  try {
    switch (event.routeKey) {
      case "DELETE /items/{id}":
        await dynamo
          .delete({
            TableName: "http-crud-tutorial-items",
            Key: {
              id: event.pathParameters.id
            }
          })
          .promise();
        body = `Deleted item ${event.pathParameters.id}`;
        break;
      case "GET /items/{id}":
        body = await dynamo
          .get({
            TableName: "http-crud-tutorial-items",
            Key: {
              id: event.pathParameters.id
            }
          })
          .promise();
        break;
      case "GET /items":
        body = await dynamo.scan({ TableName: "http-crud-tutorial-items" }).promise();
        break;
      case "PUT /items":
        let requestJSON = JSON.parse(event.body);
        await dynamo
          .put({
            TableName: "http-crud-tutorial-items",
            Item: {
              id: requestJSON.id,
              price: requestJSON.price,
              name: requestJSON.name
            }
          })
          .promise();
        body = `Put item ${requestJSON.id}`;
        break;
      default:
        throw new Error(`Unsupported route: "${event.routeKey}"`);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    statusCode = 400;
    body = err.message;
  } finally {
    body = JSON.stringify(body);
  }

  return {
    statusCode,
    body,
    headers
  };
};
```

My Routes and  integration:

```
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_route" "crud_api_route1" {
  api_id    = aws_apigatewayv2_api.crud_api.id
  route_key = "GET /items/{id}"
  target    = "integrations/${aws_apigatewayv2_integration.crud_integration.id}"
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_route" "crud_api_route2" {
  api_id    = aws_apigatewayv2_api.crud_api.id
  route_key = "GET /items"
  target    = "integrations/${aws_apigatewayv2_integration.crud_integration.id}"
}


resource "aws_apigatewayv2_route" "crud_api_route" {
  api_id    = aws_apigatewayv2_api.crud_api.id
  route_key = "PUT /items"
  target    = "integrations/${aws_apigatewayv2_integration.crud_integration.id}"
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_route" "crud_api_route3" {
  api_id    = aws_apigatewayv2_api.crud_api.id
  route_key = "DELETE /items/{id}"
  target    = "integrations/${aws_apigatewayv2_integration.crud_integration.id}"
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_integration" "crud_integration" {
  api_id             = aws_apigatewayv2_api.crud_api.id
  integration_type   = "HTTP_PROXY"
  integration_method = "POST"
  integration_uri    = "https://a7fpzomc93.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com"
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "api_gw" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromAPIGateway"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.http-crud-tutorial-function.function_name
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"

  source_arn = "${aws_apigatewayv2_api.crud_api.execution_arn}/*/*"
}
```

I just can't seem to get this going

I've looked at the routes and ensuring they were done correctly
I've done made several changes overtime working on this, a lot of errors have come and gone, but I am stuck on this one

Comment: Are you sure that `event.routeKey` is correct?

Comment: Simply print event.routeKey before the switch statement and see it's value.